# Add a border at the top of my site without an image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how to add a border at the very top of my blog.

I know how to do it with an image, with background-image and repeating horizontally.

```
body {
    background-image: url("http://bit.ly/1KTEMHF");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/9ybu5yfq/

However, am not sure how to do it if I just want a plain (smooth) border. I know I can obviously have a square as an image and that way it will work, but I imagine there's a better/easier way to do it.

So far I have found on other answers on this site that I can do it like this:

```
body {
    border-top: 15px solid #F2828E;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

(See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/uaoq6usn/ )

However, if I do it this way, the line or border, doesnt go from side to side, there's a gap, and doesnt really touch the top either.

See the difference:

[image: Example showing the difference]

Any ideas on why this happens or how could I fix it? Or there is no other way to add a border at the top of a site but with an image?

Comment: In your fiddle the border doesn't touch the edges because body has a `margin:8px` set by default. So `margin: 0` should fix it. Not sure about your blog.

Comment: Aaah cool, thanks. Gonna try now in the blog! Thanks :)

Comment: In the blog it doesnt come with a border apparentely ;) But good to know normally the body comes with that margin. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
    border-top: 15px solid #F2828E;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    margin: 0;
}
```

should do it. You essentially have a margin top by default. You can set it to zero and it'll work

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin:0`

i.e.

```
body {
  border-top: 15px solid #F2828E;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  margin:0;
}
```